# Haskell - represent Relation (from Database Theory)

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to write something that is equivalent to a relation in database theory.

```
-- A Relation has a name and a series of attributes. 
-- Each attribute might have a different type.
data Relation = Relation String [Attribute]

-- An Attribute has a name and a type
data Attribute = Attribute String Type

-- These three look like enough
data Type = String | Integer | Fixed Int
```

So, far so good.

Now we want to redefine our attribute to have assertions. Properties that must be enforced

```
data Attribute a = Attribute String Type [Assersion a]

data Assertion a where --Using GADTs
  LessThan :: Num a => a -> Assertion a
  Element :: Eq a => [a] -> Assertion a
```

Now I need to add the type parameter to the Relation, but that would force all attributes to have the same type parameter on assertions. Thus, I could not have an integer attribute and a string attribute.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Typed embeddings of relation algebra is an open research problem.

Comment: Try using an existential type to contain that type parameter inside Attribute.

Comment: Something like `data Attribute = forall a . Attribute String a [Assertion a]`. Note how there's no Type any more, your Attribute can hold *any* type. You can add a constraint so that only a specific class of types may be put in an Attribute. Actually you have to, because you can access `a` only through methods of the class you constrain it with.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I misunderstood. It seems Attribute describes a type of an attribute, not a value. If that's the case just forget about most of my previous comment and put back Type in place of the first `a`.

Comment: @DonStewart , Are there any resources available on this problem?

Comment: @MikeHartl How can I use Template Haskell when I am having problems with the type system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n.m. has the right idea, provided a Relation is supposed to be the schema of a relation, not the relation itself. Here's an example, using Data.Typeable as the class of types, and TypeRep as the representation of a type. Additionally, I want all the types to be able to be shown for the example.

```
-- Use Data.Typeable as our class of types
import Data.Typeable

data Relation = Relation String [Attribute]

data Attribute = forall a. (Typeable a, Show a) => Attribute String (Proxy a) [Assertion a]
    -- Requires RankNTypes

data Proxy a = Proxy

data Assertion a where
    LessThan :: Ord a => a -> Assertion a
    Element :: Eq a => [a] -> Assertion a
    -- Requires GADTs

-- Relation
deriving instance Show Relation

attributes (Relation _ x) = x

-- Attribute
deriving instance Show Attribute
    -- Requires StandaloneDeriving

name (Attribute x _ _) = x

validator :: Attribute -> forall a. (Typeable a) => a -> Maybe Bool
validator (Attribute _ proxy assertions) value =
    (cast value) >>= \x -> Just $ all ((flip implementation) x) assertions

dataType :: Attribute -> TypeRep
dataType (Attribute _ proxy _) = getType proxy

-- Proxy
instance (Typeable a) => Show (Proxy a) where
    show = show . getType

getType :: (Typeable a) => Proxy a -> TypeRep
getType (_ :: Proxy a) = typeOf (undefined :: a)
    -- Requires ScopedTypeVariables

-- Assertion
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (Assertion a)

implementation :: Assertion a -> a -> Bool
implementation (LessThan y) x = x < y
implementation (Element y) x = any ((==) x) y
```

The example checks to see if a couple values would be allowed for the various attributes of a relation

```
-- Example
explain :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> Attribute -> String
explain value attribute = 
    case validator attribute value of
        Nothing -> (show value) ++ " can't be a " ++ (name attribute) ++ " because it isn't a " ++ (show (dataType attribute))
        Just False -> (show value) ++ " can't be a " ++ (name attribute) ++ " because it fails an assertion"
        Just True -> (show value) ++ " can be a " ++ (name attribute)

main =
    do
    putStrLn $ show people
    sequence [ putStrLn (explain value attribute) | value <- [150 :: Int, 700], attribute <- attributes people ]
    sequence [ putStrLn (explain value attribute) | value <- ["Alice", "George"], attribute <- attributes people ]
    where
         people = Relation "People"
            [
                Attribute "Name" (Proxy :: Proxy String) [Element ["Alice", "Bob", "Eve"] ],
                Attribute "Height" (Proxy :: Proxy Int) [LessThan 300] ]
```

Here's the output of the program:

> Relation "People" [Attribute "Name" [Char] [Element
>   ["Alice","Bob","Eve"]],Attribute "Height" Int [LessThan 300]]
>
> 150 can't be a Name because it isn't a [Char]
>
> 150 can be a Height
>
> 700 can't be a Name because it isn't a [Char]
>
> 700 can't be a Height because it fails an assertion
>
> "Alice" can be a Name
>
> "Alice" can't be a Height because it isn't a Int
>
> "George" can't be a Name because it fails an assertion
>
> "George" can't be a Height because it isn't a Int

You could make your own class, using your own representation of a smaller set of types, like your `data Type`, and providing a different method of casting.